# What is a good browser level encryption product?

Tags: security, browser, encryption

I'm looking for a product that can provide browser-level encryption of textual data before it's sent to a backend server. HTTPS can be the secure transport mechanism but we need the packet to be encrypted on the browser first. The data packet must end up in encrypted form on the backend database. Use case is: user fills out form on the browser, user submits the form data, before sending the data over the wire, the browser encrypts the data, the data ends up in the backend database in encrypted form, at some point in time, all of the data will be collected from the backend database, moved to a disconnected computer and decrypted at that point.

Comment: Why is https not secure enough?

Comment: Browser-level encryption, but decryption is required in the browser? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: maybe he wants to encrypt something so that intermediary web servers cannot access the data? Maybe? Oh, I don't know...

Comment: HTTPS is not secure enough for all clients. Some of them require higher level encryption than that.

Comment: @Jeff What is "higher level encryption" supposed to mean? As I said in my answer, SSL supports a vast array of ciphers and key lengths. You can go as "high" as you have to.

Comment: @NullUserException I could have elaborated to mention application tiers/soa etc, but was just a general statement. @Jeff - ok, I have no idea where you are getting your information

Comment: TLS/X.509 is actually really bad, but in practice it's good enough because everything else (web protocols, browsers, everything on your os including it, hardware) are much worse. In any case, if you want actual security, avoid the web at all costs.

Comment: @Longpoke I like the way you look at things.

Comment: If you need a higher level of security than HTTPS SSL/TLS, your best bet will be to shut down the server, lock it in a vault, and throw away the key. Basically the internet is not the place for mission critical data that cannot see the light of day.

Comment: Are you wanting to store the data in the database in it's encrypted form?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, wanting to store the data in the database in encrypted form. At some point in time, all of the data will be collected, moved to a super secret disconnected computer and decrypted at that point. The data must be encrypted on the browser before submission, sent over the wire in encrypted form and stored in the database in encrypted form.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: no that's not true at all, it's in fact trivial to write a secure server (server, not web server), just not with mainstream technology (unsafe instruction sets, web, gigantic code bases that do not following principal of least privilege, lack of distinction of code from data/parameters, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what HTTPS (SSL/TLS) is for.  It should be plenty secure enough.

But as you state in your answer to my query, you want the form data to be stored in the database in its encrypted form.  A quick Google search brings up [JQuery.Gibberish-AES](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-Gibberish-AES).  It's a JQuery plugin that will do AES encryption and can utilise an RSA public key.

Using this you could generate a public/private key pair, keep the private key on the super-secret disconnected computer, and publish the public key with your form.  You can then encrypt the data, store it in your database, and even if someone got root access to the database server they could decrypt the data because the secret key is on your secure disconnected machine.

I'm sure there'd be similar plug-ins/libraries for other client-side frameworks if you don't use JQuery.

I'd still use SSL/TLS for the connection, because that provides the server authentication (and client authentication if you want) to protect against a man-in-the-middle.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP over SSL/TLS (HTTPS) *is* secure enough. It actually is as secure as it gets.

With SSL/TLS you can choose the cipher suite and adjust the encryption algorithms and key sizes according to your needs. 2048-bit RSA and 256-bit AES should be secure enough.

In addition to encryption, SSL provides authentication. AND it is natively supported by virtually every browser in existence. Please don't [reinvent the wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604582/which-attacks-are-possible-concerning-my-security-layer-concept/3604619#3604619).

Comment: Thanks. My mistake in phrasing the question. We want the packet to be secured prior to transport and then to live in the database in encrypted form. HTTPS is fine but we want to encrypt the packet before transporting it.

Comment: @Jeff Is the intent of this to make the data private to the server receiving it? In other words, do your clients not want you to be able to see their data?

Comment: @NullUserExceptoin That's right. The data will arrive encrypted and be stored in the database in encrypted form. At some point in the future it will be transferred manually to a disconnected machine and decrypted there.

Comment: @Jeff I see. Is this just text we are talking about? How large would each submission be?

Comment: Yes, just text. Very trivial, likely < 1KB

Answer (score 3):

I agree that TLS is good enough for a lot of cases and I've [written a little about it](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) in my journey to see how it works. It does have some issues like [governments being able to compel certificate authorities to grant certificates to allow man-in-the-middle attacks](http://files.cloudprivacy.net/ssl-mitm.pdf), but in general it's pretty good.

You might be interested in the design of systems like LastPass that encrypt things *in addition* to using TLS (details [here](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-229.htm)). I would say that your best approach if you think TLS isn't good enough is to do something in addition to it rather than in lieu of it.