# AES-256-CBC encryption console vs web php

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, openssl, aes

Hi i have problem with aes-256-cbc encryption. I want encrypt some text in php and after that decrypt it in javascrypt with pidCrypt library.

EDIT: 
I try to decrypt online here:
https://www.pidder.de/pidcrypt/?page=demo_aes-cbc

In console working everything ok (encrypt in php decrypt in pidCrypt) i type this command: (OpenSSL v. 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014)

```
echo "some text to en/decrypt"|openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a
pass: 123456789
```

I get this:

```
U2FsdGVkX18c8uPBYdA0af5odtv2WA0Y4a2LhlB3xGUo6pAodMVMAckXr0XcUbJ8
```

But in php file on server (OpenSSL v. 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013 **OR** 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011 result is the same)

```
$encrypted = @openssl_encrypt('some text to en/decrypt', 'aes-256-cbc', '123456789');
```

I get this:

```
Pqmtan2DSnGKe87JbOmzD5Rz04T3Nwa4K8zqsohPWec=
```

Outputs are not the same (php file vs console command) and second output can not be decrypted in pidCrypt (but in php file on server yes)

Can anybody help? Why are not result the same? What i must do when i want output as from console?

Comment: Everything is explained about command line vs PHP function in the PHP documentation
[http://php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-encrypt.php#104438](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-encrypt.php#104438)

Comment: But my issue is not with decrypt in PHP that it works. In first case i have not tried it because it working (php encrypt and js decrypt) And with second case (only PHP) is en/decryption working WITHOUT strtohex function like this: `openssl_decrypt('Pqmtan2DSnGKe87JbOmzD5Rz04T3Nwa4K8zqsohPWec=', 'aes-256-cbc', '123456789'); ` But on javascript side is not decryption working even if i use strtohex function...

Comment: Similar question is asking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247083/javascript-php-encryption-with-pidcrypt tell me if this is not helping

Comment: Sadly no :( I tried to multiple options from yours link but RSA en/decoding i have and it works fine. (php encode and js decode). I just simple need the same result from executable php file as from console... That's all folks! :)

Comment: Can you add in your original post more details, encryption in PHP, decryption in JS and encryption in JS and decryption in PHP with your code, it's a bit confusing

Comment: The problem stems probably from the misconception that the `password` argument for the `openssl_encrypt` function in PHP is the same as the pass parameter of the commandline tool. It is not. It is the key which may be derived from the password.

Comment: Ok so can you write more? How i can get key? Is enough convert password to HEX? (because it dont work)

Comment: If you just want to encrypt with a key, I suggest you read up on how to specify the key and IV in hex in the command line tool. Otherwise you may be required to implement the OpenSSL proprietary key derivation mechanism in PHP....

Comment: More information [here](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_BytesToKey%283%29)